# By default, does a linksys router log connections?

Tags: network, logging

Routers have many settings that allow it to be safe and secure for the users that are connected to that network. A lot of these settings have to be manually configured though, which includes configuring the username and password to log into the router, cloaking the SSID, and so on.

I began wondering how many of these settings, by default, were not enabled. I did some research, but I was not able to get one question answered. Does a linksys router by default log any connections to websites that were previously visited? I checked my router, which is an ARRIS modem/router combo and I found that the logging option was not enabled. Would it be the same scenario with a linksys router?

Follow-up question as well: How long does the router keep its connection logs for? Can it get full enough to the point where the router just dumps all the data, or does it just clear itself over time?

Comment: I don't really know, but I think it's highly unlikely, especially for a consumer model such as Linksys. Consumer models are made to be cheap and do just what users and ISPs need it to do: create a NAT, perhaps a WiFi network, and not much else. The logging option never decently worked for me, even when turning it on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logging is disabled by default on LinkSys routers. The following is a quote from the LinkSys WRT54G user guide:

> The Router can keep logs of all traffic for your Internet connection.
>   To disable the Log function, keep the default setting, Disable. To
>   monitor traffic between the network and the Internet, select Enable.

Routers will generally store the last N connections in a [cyclic buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer).